# What to check when testing controllers in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testing, controller

I am testing controllers in simple Sprinng application using MockMvc. It is first time I am trying to do testing. Based on resources I found, I am successfully running my tests, but I am not sure about what to check on responses. My controllers only return name of views to be rendered:
index page (contains menu bar and welcome text), product page (contains menu bar and empty table of products) and about page (again menu bar and some info about author).
Tests looks like this:

```
    mockMvc.perform(get("/myviews"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(view().name("myviewsnames"))
    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/myviewsjsps.jsp"));
```

But based on MockMvcResultMatchers documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html
I see a lot of other options for matching. What else, and why, should I check in my tests? Thank you.

Comment: You may also want to test exception handling. Spring MVC controllers can translate exceptions thrown by your service layer to HTTP Status (e.g. bad request, unauthorized, not found, etc). Yet this may make more sense for Rest Controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually MockMvc is a great way to test RESTful web services, you can test your responses based on their headers, status code and response body. In the case of your use case you can test your view name based on some request criteria if any exist.

Comment: Thank you. I will implement REST controllers and tests later too. But what I mean is, does it make sense to test, lets say, headers even when I am not modifying it? Or should I check if appropriate handler handled my request? In examples with REST controllers I always see checking if no other methods of mock object are called during the test. Why do we need to test this?

Comment: You're welcome, Imagine you update your Entity with put method, so you expect `Last-Modified` header value should be changed, you test it in your case. You request XML representation of the resource,in the case of supporting this mime type  you expect your response `Content-Type` will change, and in the case of not supporting your mime type you should except `415 Unsupported Media Type` status code, actually you test your code based on your use cases, and your expectations from your code.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot!